# Is it possible to add get all the events from a google calendar?

Tags: php, calendar

Is it possible to add get all the events from a google calendar? I can create a calendar view exactly from google calendar by embedding to my website (I'm using php), but I want only to get title, details, and when of all the events only. And put it on a list on my website.
I want that if I add a event on my google calendar, the list from my website will also be updated.
I only need title, description or details and date of events from google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you render the website, you can use the RSS feed from the google calendar/the JSON API to the google calendar to fetch the data you need.

By doing this dynamically you can make sure any new events are replicated.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I got it, but problem now is the date. When I fetch the date event, I got this info. "When: Thu Jun 25, 2015". I only need the june 25 to compare something on the database, 2015. Also, calendar information are being converted automatically basing on the country.

Comment: Those are mere string manipulations. You can format it however you want using the String APIs of php. Refer [link](https://php.net/ref.strings). But yeah.. I guess the API could include these features as well. 
You can account for timezones using datetime libraries in php.

Comment: Thanks Kartik, already found solution and it's also one of the list you've shared.